# Not able to start fresh install of create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Tapping back into node after a long break and am having issues with some of my older projects as well as a brand new install of create-react-app. In all cases starting the build fails with:

`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE`
`npm ERR! errno 1`
`npm ERR! react-spring@0.1.0 start:` react-scripts start``
`npm ERR! Exit status 1`
`npm ERR!`
`npm ERR! Failed at the react-spring@0.1.0 start script.`

My node version is v14.16.1 and have tried to run npm install or npm install react-scripts@latest to no avail. Running cache clean didn't help either. Any clues as to why this is happening? Is there a specific react-scripts version I need to install?

Comment: Are you running this in the directory of your `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

If you already tried `npm install`, as well as `npm install react-scripts` you might get it to work by using `npm install --only=dev`.

This will install the dev dependencies (`react-scripts`) as well.